# How to start Neovim terminal in full window?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I know the equivalent command in Vim is:

```
:terminal ++curwin
```

How do I do the same thing in Neovim?

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neovim default is different. Neovim terminal start by default in full screen:

```
:terminal
```